# How does SAS identifies the End of Observation while reading data from csv?

Tags: csv, sas

My csv file sales.csv has 8 variables

Employee_ID ,First_Name ,Last_Name,  Gender, Salary ,Job_Title ,country and Emp_Hire_Date

my code is like this :

```
%let path = /folders/myfolders/ecprg193;
data work.sales1;
   infile "&path/sales.csv" dlm=',';  
   input Employee_ID First_Name $
         Last_Name $ Gender $ Salary
         Job_Title $ Country $;
run;
```

it is basically creation of dataset sales1 from the csv file.

In the code as u can see I hav specified till country variable. 
**My question is while creating data set work.sales1 how sas Skips the hiredate data in CSV** ?

Let me know if any more information is required to answer this question.

Comment: Can you show a few example lines of the data file?  Also when you ran your program did SAS generate any error messages?

Comment: SAS didnt gave any error message I hav checked the logs.
Text of first 2 rows as copied from input file sales.csv 
.....

120102,Tom,Zhou,M,108255,Sales Manager,AU,11AUG1973                  
120103,Wilson,Dawes,M,87975,Sales Manager,AU,22JAN1953
.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your description your file has 8 fields per line and your program is only reading 7 variables per line.  So it skips the last field because you never read it.

By default SAS will expect variable length records that are separated by the normal end-of-line characters for your operating system. It looks like from your path you are running SAS on Unix so the default end-of-line will be just the linefeed character ('0A'x).  If you created the file on a PC then most likely it actually was created using carriage return and linefeed two byte sequence ('0D0A'x) as the end-of-line.  You can tell SAS which one to use by adding the `TERMSTR=` option to the `INFILE` statement.  So add `termstr=CRLF` if you are reading a PC/Windows file on Unix.

Comment: yes line feed char is the delimiter for each row as per your observation. Infact, your answer is exact and precise thanks :)

Comment: One more thing if you can see the infile statement, I have specified only delimiter (,)for value of each variable not for end of row/observation. hence by default  ('0A'x) is the observation delimiter. What if i want to specify the observation delimiter explicitely, Can u tell me more about this, how to add one?